# How to remove datetime from a Logfile string

Tags: c#, substring

I have a logfile like this:

> [2016 01 10 11:10:44] Operation3 \r\n
>
> [2016 01 10 11:10:40] Operation2 \r\n
>
> [2016 01 10 11:10:36] Operation1 \r\n

on that I perform a readAlllines operation so that in a string I have:

```
[2016 01 10 11:10:44] Operation3 \r\n[2016 01 10 11:10:40] Operation2 \r\n[2016 01 10 11:10:36] Operation1 \r\n
```

Now I have to remove all those timestamps.

Being a newbie and to be on the safe side I'd split it and the search on each item for start=indexOf("[") and indexOf("]") and the remove the subString by cutting each and then join all of them.

I'd like to know a smarter way to do that.

--EDIT--
Ok for downvoting me I didn't considered everything.
additional constraints:

1. I can't be sure of the fact that all line have the timestamp so I have to check each line for a "[" starting and a "]" in the middle
2. I can't even be sure for the [XXXX] lenght since I could have [2016 1 1 11:1:4] instead than [2016 01 01 11:01:04]. So it's important to check for its lenght.

Thanks

Comment: "Smarter" is not SMART. Does this work? Then why look for alternatives?

Comment: what about a regular expression?

Comment: If the time stanp is a consistent length just trim the length off the front of the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to cut/paste the lines, you can use string.replace.
This takes into account the lenght of Environment.NewLine.

```
 while(true)
 {
  int start; 
  if (lines.Substring(0,1) == "[")
    start = 0;
  else
    start = lines.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine + "[") + Environment.NewLine.Length;
  int end = lines.IndexOf("] ");
  if (start == -1 || end == -1)
    break;
  string subString = lines.Substring(start, end + 2 - start);
  lines = lines.Replace(subString, "");
 }
```

Comment: Not very different from my solution but a big better

Answer (score 1):

[ReadAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx) returns an array of lines, so you don't need to look for the start of each item.  If your timestamp format will be consistent, you can just trim off the start of the string.

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("log.txt");
foreach (string line in lines) 
{
    string logContents = line.SubString("[XXXX XX XX XX:XX:XX] ".Length);
}
```

Or combine this with a linq Select to do it in one step

```
var logContentsWithoutTimestamps = File.ReadAllLines("log.txt")
    .Select(x => x.SubString("[XXXX XX XX XX:XX:XX] ".Length);
```

Without consistent format, you will need to identify what you are looking for.  I would write a regular expression to remove what you are looking for, otherwise you may get caught by things you weren't expecting (for example, you mention that some lines may not have timestamps - they might have something else in square brackets instead which you don't want to remove).

Example:

```
Regex rxTimeStamp = new Regex("^\[\d{4} \d{2} \d{2} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\]\s*");
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("log.txt");
foreach (string line in lines) 
{
    string logContents = rxTimeStamp.Replace(line, String.Empty);
}

// or
var logContentsWithoutTimestamps = File.ReadAllLines("log.txt")
    .Select(x => rxTimeStamp.Replace(x, String.Empty));
```

You'll need to tune the regular expression based on whether it misses anything, but that's beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: sorry for being late. lines is not a String[] but a string of the kind explained in my question

Comment: File.ReadAllLines returns an array of strings, which means you don't have to worry about splitting lines yourself.  I suggest you use it, or use a StreamReader with ReadLine.  While it is possible to do what you want with the whole string, why make it harder?

Comment: You are right Richard but I am linking my function to another function that reads/writes log files not done by me. Would it be difficult to tune your answer to my needs? thanx

Answer (score 0):

Since your code works and you search for some different way:

```
 string result = string.Join(string.Empty, str.Skip(22));
```

for each item

Explanation:
Since every timestamp is of equal length you don`t need to search for beginning or end. Normally you would have to do length checks (empty lines etc) but this works even for smaller strings - you will just get an empty string in return if the size is < 22. An alternative way if your file really just contains timestamps.